# Spring JPA intersect two list fields of an entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have a entity called `A` which has one property `userGroups`:

```
@entity
Public class A {

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "a_user_groups", ...)
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;
...
}
```

I need to find those `A` entities which their `userGroups` has no intersection with given `Set<UserGroup> userGroups` parameter.

This is my method:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE :userGroups intersect a.userGroups is NULL")
List<A> getAWithNoIntersectionInGroups(@param("userGroups") Set<UserGroup> userGroups)
```

But there is no `intersect` keyword in jpa.

`Not In` keyword not works here:

Suppose there is an `A` entity with user groups ids `{1,3}` and my passed user group ids are `{3,4}`, Now `{1,3}` is not in `{3,4}` and it's true and entity will be selected, but it shouldn't selected, because there is a mutual item `{3}`

Comment: can't you run SQL query by making native=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *NOT IN* SQL clause instead intersect.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.userGroups not in (:userGroups)")
List<A> getAWithNoIntersectionInGroups(@param("userGroups") Set<UserGroup> userGroups)
```

Comment: This will not work, Suppose there is an `A` entity with user groups ids  `{1,3}` and my passed user group ids are `{3,4}`, Now `{1,3}` is not in `{3,4}` and it's true and entity will be selected, but it shouldn't selected, because there is a mutual item (`3`)

Comment: To Understand it clearly can you mark which among the following should be given true and false,
You have entity A with {1,3} and you compare with,
{1,3}
{1,2}
{3,4}
{2,4}
Out of these 3 which one(or all) of them should be true.

Comment: {1,3} with {1,3} = true ,,  
{1,3} with {1,2} = false

Comment: {1,3} with {3,4} = false

Comment: {1,3} with {2,4} = false

Comment: Only {1,3} with {1,3} should be true logically.

Comment: then you can use = instead of all these. 
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.userGroups = :userGroups
Try this, I think it should work

Comment: select 1 from dual where (1,2) = (1,2) This is valid SQL query, then it should work with HQL as well. You can try this.

Comment: You mean using not equals? `!=` ?

Comment: exactly, either equals or not equals based on what output you need.